# How do i can create IR in apex oracle based on different table and column

Tags: oracle-apex

IR based on PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query.

How do i can create Interactive reports based on multiple table and Deferent column name.

Exp :-
Select list  item return three value 
1 or 2 or 3

And the function return query basen on select list value

when Value equal 1

Select name, satate, country_id from cities

when value equal 2 Return

Select country, id from country

when value equal 3 Return

Select ocean,oc_id,from oceans

The three query return different column name and value.

Answer (score 1):

Ok firstly, your question is poorly written. But from what I gather, you want an SQL query that returns different things based on an input.

I dont think you even need a plsql function body for this.

Simply do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT name as name,
       state as state,
       country_id as id,
       1 as value
  FROM cities
UNION ALL
SELECT country as name,
       NULL as state,
       id as id,
       2 as value
  FROM country
UNION ALL
SELECT ocean as name,
       NULL as state,
       oc_id as id,
       3 as value
  FROM oceans)
 WHERE value = :input_parameter_value;
```

Because if you are trying to display a variable number of columns and constantly changing their names and such. You are gonna have a bad time, it can be done, as can everything. But afaik its not exactly simple

Comment: Sorry for that but I am not good in english, but i don't know what the column in query, the users choose any column they needs and the query generated automatically and save it into  table, after that the user can choose the query name from the list, so that why used the plsql function

Comment: @jaw So from what I can tell, you want to basically have users choose their own sql query and you want a report to display it. Thats not really how apex works. Apex wants basically a fixed report, with names and sizes etc., and then you fill it.
So either you have one report that you fill as I suggested, or you set up multiple reports, and depending on what you choose only one shows up.
Perfectly dynamic stuff like you want can be achieved, but that is done with some dynamic plsql regions and apex_item magics. That is very high level stuff and will take even pros many days to build

Answer (score 1):

No objections to what @TineO has said in their answer, I'd probably do it that way.

Though, yet another option: if your Apex version allows it, you can create three Interactive Report regions on the same page, each selecting values from its own table, keeping its own column labels.

Then create a **server condition** for each region; its type would be *Function that returns a Boolean* and look like

```
return :P1_LIST_ITEM = 1;
```

for the 1st region; `= 2` for the 2nd and `= 3` for the 3rd.

When you run the page, nothing would be displayed as `P1_LIST_ITEM` has no value. Once you set it, one of conditions would be met and appropriate region would be displayed.

Comment: Sorry for that but I am not good in english, but i don't know what the column in query, the users choose any column they needs and the query generated automatically and save it into  table, after that the user can choose the query name from the list, so that why used the plsql function, thanks for your support

Comment: Dear ,
if you know how i can do this please  ,tell me how  ,i have a deadline after tomorrow
thanks

Comment: From my point of view, that's not how Apex works. If you use my suggestion (described in answer), then every user has an option to choose whichever columns they wanted (from IR's "Actions" menu) and even save any number of their own reports (again via the "Actions" menu). I'd suggest you not to reinvent the wheel.